# How to get the next page from Get-AzureAutomationJobOutput

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-automation, powershell-workflow

I am using this code to get job output messages:

```
$jobOutput = Get-AzureAutomationJobOutput -AutomationAccountName $AutomationAccountName -Id $RunbookJobId -Stream "Any" -verbose
```

It only returns the first 100 messages.

How can I get the next 100 messages?

Can I just increase the page size?

I'd prefer to not get the time stamp of the last object and add 1ms to that and use that as the new -StartTime. Because there could be multiple messages with the same time stamp.
I'd also prefer to not have to do that and check for duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in the Azure Automation cmdlets. We do not currently let you choose the page size, or specify a page # to retrieve, via the cmdlets. We have it on the backlog to fix, but no ETA right now.